# Sums of $f(f(x))=1-x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

We consider all real functions $f$ with the property $f(f(x))=1-x$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$. We define for each such function $f$ the sum:
$$S_f=f(-2017)+f(-2016)+...+f(-1)+f(0)+f(1)...+f(2017)+f(2018)$$

Determine the set of all values ​​that such sums $S_f$ can take.

To find solutions for function $f$ I used [this solution](https://www.quora.com/If-f-f-x-1-x-then-what-is-f-x/answer/Martin-Pettet-1).

Comment: Can you cite the source of this particular problem?

Comment: @amWhy "Methods of Solving Nonstandard Problems" by Ellina Grigorieva but I just have an excerpt of it. So the solution is 
unfortunately missing.

Comment: Thank you, D.Pubusky!

Comment: @amWhy your welcome

Answer (score 10):

Since $$1-f(x)=f(f(f(x))) = f(1-x)\implies \boxed{f(1-x)+f(x)=1}$$ so

$$ f(-2017)+f(2018)=1$$
$$ f(-2016)+f(2017)=1$$
$$ \vdots$$
$$ f(-1)+f(2)=1$$
$$ f(0)+f(1)=1$$

So $S_f = 2018$.

Comment: Might be missing something obvious but why does $1-f(x)=f(f(f(x)))$?

Comment: Write $y= f(x)$ and $1-y=f(f(y))$

Comment: Of course—thanks